# JavaScript: Calling a function inside an object literal doesn't work in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have this object literal in my app which looks something like this:

```
var user = {
    func1: function() {
        // do some stuff
    },

    func2: function() {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

and whenever I try to do this:

```
user.func1();
```

it fails in Internet Explorer 8 with the following error:

```
Object doesn't support this method or property
```

I've tried doing this:

```
user['func1']();
```

and I get the same error

EDIT: I've tried replacing all calls to object literals with just normal or anonymous functions and that seems to work fine. However, I still want make this work as I don't want to rewrite all my code:

EDIT: Here are the relevant javascript files:

[app.js](http://pastebin.com/xcwnn9PC)

[user.js](http://pastebin.com/9ccer116)

Comment: From the code provided, it _should_ work. Do you get different behavior in other browsers?

Comment: It works absolutely fine in all other browsers

Comment: I've tried running the code in ie8, and with a simple `alert` within `func1`, it can call `user.func1()` perfectly. Would you be able to provide any sample code that you're using in the actual functions?

Comment: I've just updated my answer which includes links to the relevant JS files. Note that I'm also using jQuery 1.10.2